# about bijective function and continous functions .

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ are continous functions and $f(g(x))$ is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) .

> prove $f$ and $g$ are also bijective .

i think because  $f(g(x))$ is bijective then $g$ is one to one and $f$ is surjective .

If $x \ne y$ but $g(x) = g(y)$ then $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$; so $f \circ g$ injective $=> g$ injective.

If there is no $y$ such that $f(y) = z$ then there is no $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x)) = z$; so if $f \circ g$ is surjective, $f$ must be surjective.

so we must show $f$ is one to one and $g$ is surjective and use continuity of $f$ and $g$ .

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What you are looking for is false, try to find any two functions $f$ and $g$ such that their composition is the identity, for example.

Comment: @Zaragosa Funny. I could bet that the statement is true.

Comment: @Zaragosa no, it is true.

Comment: Hint: It is not true if $f,g$ are not continuous. So far, you have not used continuity.

Comment: Discontinuous example: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x<0\\0&x\in[0,1]\\x-1&x>1\end{cases}\\g(x)=\begin{cases}x&x<0\\x+1&x\geq 0\end{cases}$$ Here, $f$ is continuous, but $g$ is not, and $f(g(x))=x.$

Comment: They are very right, I did not read completely, the continuity must make it true.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $g$ is a continuous injective function. Therefore, $g$ is monotonic. Without loss of generality, take $g$ to be strictly increasing. Also, without loss of generality, take $f \circ g$ to be strictly increasing (since $f \circ g$ is also a continuous injective function).

We wish to show that the range of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

To do this, we show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} g(x) = \pm \infty$ and apply the intermediate value theorem. I will just show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$.

In particular, note that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} g(x)$, since $g$ is increasing. Thus, the limit is either finite or infinite.

Suppose the limit is finite. Then we have $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(g(x)) = f(\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x))$ by the continuity of $f$. But because $f \circ g$ is an increasing bijection, we must have $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(g(x)) = \infty$. Contradiction. Therefore, the limit must be infinite.

Using the intermediate value theorem, we can therefore establish that the range of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $g$ is a surjection, hence a bijection. Therefore, $f = (f \circ g) \circ g^{-1})$ is the composition of 2 bijections, hence a bijection.